# install Oracle11gr2 on Windows 2008 R2 failed to install "Oracle Net Configuration Assistant”

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, oracle11gr2

log file shows:

```
INFO: Starting 'Oracle Net Configuration Assistant'
INFO: 
INFO: Parsing command line arguments:
INFO:     Parameter "orahome" = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
INFO:     Parameter "orahnam" = OraDb11g_home1
INFO:     Parameter "instype" = typical
INFO:     Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
INFO:     Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp,nmp
INFO:     Parameter "cfg" = local
INFO:     Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
INFO:     Parameter "responsefile" = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\install\netca_typ.rsp
INFO:     Parameter "silent" = true
INFO: Done parsing command line arguments.
INFO: Oracle Net Services Configuration:
INFO: #
INFO: # An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
INFO: #
INFO: #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000006c7eb3f, pid=3972, tid=3440
INFO: #
INFO: # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.5.0_17-b04 mixed mode)
INFO: # Problematic frame:
INFO: # C  [oranl11.dll+0x3eb3f]
INFO: #
INFO: # An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid3972.log
INFO: #
INFO: # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
INFO: #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
INFO: #
INFO: 
WARNING: 
INFO: Completed Plugin named: Oracle Net Configuration Assistant
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a Java JVM crash.  That's a very old JVM you're using, though, so you should upgrade to the more recent stable version (1.6.0_25 at time of writing) and try again.